# Finding shared AMI (with my account) on my AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

My colleague has shared an AMI from his account to mine. This has been confirmed. On his AWS console , he went to AMI screen and did modify permissions and added my account and did "save".

However, when I logged on to my account and went to AMI screen (under EC2), I still only see my AMIs.

How can I see the AMI he shared with my account? (I have admin rights on my account).

Thank you!

Comment: AMIs that have been shared with your account show up under the `Private images` filter. Can you find the shared AMI under this filter?

Comment: boom! That was it. Thank you!

Comment: Great - I'll make an answer with this info :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AMIs that have been shared with your account show up under the `Private images` filter. Can you find the shared AMI under this filter?

[image]

Comment: Yup. That was it. Thank you!